# How to modify spacing around quotation environment?

Tags: spacing, environments, quoting

I am almost there in my quest to reproduce the rather compact layout of the book I'm translating... one thing to go, though:

I successfully used the `enumitem` package to modify the vertical and horizontal spacing of the various list environments.

But how do I modify the vertical and horizontal spacing of the `quotation` environment? I have found lots of information on how to do it for theorems and formulas etc., but none of that seems to apply for `quotation` (or `quote`, for that matter).

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{leftmargin=*,parsep=0pt,itemsep=2pt,topsep=2pt,partopsep=0pt}
\setlist[enumerate]{widest=0}

\newcommand{\sometext}{Some random text. Not using lipsum as I don't need that much text.}

\begin{document}
\sometext
\begin{itemize}
\item One item.
\item Another item.
\end{itemize}
\sometext
\begin{quotation}
\textbf{Note:} \emph{This has too much whitespace around it.}
\end{quotation}
\sometext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The [`quoting`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/quoting) package provides a `quoting` environment with customizable font, margins, spacing... Just load it with `\usepackage{quoting}` and use either `\begin{quoting}[vskip=0pt] ... \end{quoting}` or set it up globally with `\quotingsetup{vskip=0pt}`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{leftmargin=*,parsep=0pt,itemsep=2pt,topsep=2pt,partopsep=0pt}
\setlist[enumerate]{widest=0}

\usepackage{quoting}
\quotingsetup{vskip=0pt}

\newcommand{\sometext}{Some random text. Not using lipsum as I don't need that much text.}

\begin{document}
\sometext
\begin{itemize}
\item One item.
\item Another item.
\end{itemize}
\sometext
\begin{quoting}
\textbf{Note:} \emph{This has no extra white\-space around it.}
\end{quoting}
\sometext
\end{document}
```

[image: output result]

Comment: Ummm, the word `whitespace` is a well-known case of a failure of TeX's hyphenation mechanism... You may want to add a discretionary hyphen, `\-`, to fix this in your MWE. :-)

Comment: @Mico Thanks for pointing that out, fixed :-)

Comment: I find setting parameters for a package preferrable over redefining, or writing macros myself. (Assuming that the package authors know more about LaTeX than I do, which isn't hard at all.) Thanks for pointing out this package.

Comment: Global settings may also be changed using `\usepackage[vskip=0pt]{quoting}`.

Answer (score 20):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrbook}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{quotation}
               {\list{}{\listparindent=0pt%whatever you need
                        \itemindent    \listparindent
                        \leftmargin=0pt%  whatever you need
                        \rightmargin=10pt%whatever you need
                        \topsep=0pt%%%%%  whatever you need
                        \parsep        \z@ \@plus\p@}%
                \item\relax}
               {\endlist}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\sometext}{Some random text. Not using lipsum as I don't need that much text.}

\begin{document}

\sometext
\begin{quotation}
\textbf{Note:} \emph{This has too much whitespace around it.}
\end{quotation}
\sometext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to `\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}` at the global level, but it did not seem to affect the `quotation` environment, so I thought it had to be some other parameter... but it seems that the `\topsep` etc. has to be declared explicitly *in* the environent... is there a simple explanation as to why?

Comment: your value is always overwritten by the definition of `quotation`

Comment: On second thought, isn't this somewhat... I won't call it "buggy", but perhaps "flaky"? If the environment ignores global `topsep` settings, shouldn't it react on some other setting? Having to re-define the environment to change one parameter strikes me as a bit heavy-handed, especially since LaTeX apparently does not provide a way to either determine the standard definition for reference ("what are all the *other* things done by this environment, so I don't forget them in my redifinition"), or add a single value to the definition *without* having to redefine it completely...

Comment: Although I don't know much about it, the "toolbox" package might be a little more elegant.  That being said, this is great; in no small part because one doesn't have to define ERT before and after each quotation in Lyx.