# Make all \begin{quote} ... \end{quote} blocks single spaced with setspace?

Tags: spacing, line-spacing, quoting, article, setspace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reduce the space between a quotation and a title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34526/reduce-the-space-between-a-quotation-and-a-title)

I am writing a double-spaced paper using the `setspace` package. I need quotations to be formatted with single spacing, however. So my paper looks something like:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}
\doublespacing

Double-spaced document body here...

\begin{quote}
\singlespacing
    Single-spaced quote text here...
\end{quote}

More double-spaced document body here...

\end{document}
```

Is there a way I can avoid the `\singlespacing` command inside the `\begin{quote} ... \end{quote}` block, so that all such blocks default to single spacing?

Comment: You can look at [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34526/reduce-the-space-between-a-quotation-and-a-title/34529#34529) which probably solves your problem.