# Problems with quoting package and renewing quotation environment

Tags: environments, quoting

Following this [How to modify spacing around quotation environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29640/how-to-modify-spacing-around-quotation-environment)
...I have tried to use both given solutions (using [`quoting`](http://ctan.org/pkg/quoting) package and renewing `quotation` environment). I cannot use `quoting` package (MiKTeX does not find it, it is recognized by the newest version of MiKTeX but I am finishing my thesis so do not want to ruin my previous work by updating MiKTeX or do anything as such :) - I am not a pro etc. ;)), so I have tried this:

```
\renewenvironment{quotation}
               {\list{}{\listparindent=0pt%whatever you need
                        \itemindent    \listparindent
                        \leftmargin=0pt%  whatever you need
                        \rightmargin=10pt%whatever you need
                        \topsep=0pt%%%%%  whatever you need
                        \parsep        \z@ \@plus\p@}%
                \item\relax}
               {\endlist}
```

However it does not work. I have got this in the log file:

```
! Undefined control sequence. ...tmargin =10pt\topsep =0pt\parsep \z 
@ \@plus\p @ l.319 \begin{quotation}
```

**EDIT: the solution is to not miss the 
    \makeatletter
before the code
and
    \makeatother
after the code
(I did not include the full code)**

Have you any ideas, why I cannot use it?

Or how to define  spaces (mainly - block stretching it) between `quotation` environment and paragraphs (the spaces are not the same in different quotations in the text, sometimes the space is uneven before and after quotation or the space is huge, so the output does not look good as it should and I have to add or reduce `vspace`, which is probably the worst solution taking into account why I use `TeX`).

Comment: Would you be able to include an entire [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) of what you currently have, rather than just a snippet of code.

Comment: You have to use `\makeatletter` before the redefiniton and should use `\makeatother` after it, because of the `@` character in `\z@` and further control sequences. See [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do) for an explanation.

Comment: That is the solution. I did not used \makeatletter and \makeatother

Comment: It was my first question, sorry for breaking a rule with MWE... Actually the problem was with using just a snippet of code -- so maybe with EDIT it will be more useful for the others (newbies here like me :)) not to follow the same mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following works for me; note the use of `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{quotation}
               {\list{}{\listparindent=0pt%whatever you need
                        \itemindent    \listparindent
                        \leftmargin=0pt%  whatever you need
                        \rightmargin=10pt%whatever you need
                        \topsep=0pt%%%%%  whatever you need
                        \parsep        \z@ \@plus\p@}%
                \item\relax}
               {\endlist}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

Before the quote \ldots
\begin{quotation}
\lipsum[1]
\end{quotation}
After the quote \ldots
\end{document}
```

Comment: ok :), I will try to figure out how to do it :).

Comment: @Karo: I merged your unregistered account and your registered account (which you used for posting the question), now you can accept by clicking the check mark on the left of the answer. I also converted the answer to a comment.

Comment: I have quotations within the eledpar double column environment, this technique doesn't seem to work for me, any suggestions?