# Changing the vertical spacing before and after the quoting environment when using parskip

Tags: spacing, quoting, parskip

I'm working with the [`quoting`](http://ctan.org/pkg/quoting) environment but I can't figure out how to adjust the vertical space before and after it. I would like the environment to be indented on either side like it is but not have a full paragraph return before or after it.

The `quoting` documentation says that the space at the top of a quote is controlled by `vskip`. I have tried adjusting the `vskip` option to `vskip=-8pt` but it didn't do anything. I also tried adding a `\noindent` before the `quoting` environment--also didn't do anything.

Here is a minimal working example.

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}% use "amsart" instead of "article" for AMSLaTeX format
% TeX will automatically convert eps --> pdf in pdflatex        
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}           %use line breaks instead of indentation

\usepackage{quoting}    %For inset quotes more than three lines

\title{Brief Article}
\author{The Author}
%\date{}                            % Activate to display a given date or no date

\begin{document}
\maketitle
%\section{}
%\subsection{}
\blindtext

\begin{quoting} 
This is a quote which should be indented but should not have a full
paragraph line before it or after it. In other words it should be
indented on either side but shouldn't have a full paragraph skip before.
\end{quoting}

\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `vskip=-\parskip` option seems to do the trick.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\usepackage[vskip=-\parskip]{quoting}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{quoting} 
This is a quote which should be indented but should not have a full
paragraph line before it or after it. In other words it should be
indented on either side but shouldn't have a full paragraph skip before.
\end{quoting}

\blindtext

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is some conflict between `quoting` and `parskip`. If you comment out the `\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}` line, then the `[vskip=0pt]` option after `\begin{quoting}` works as expected.
[image]

Also, this looks like a duplicate of [How to modify spacing around quotation environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29640/how-to-modify-spacing-around-quotation-environment)

Comment: Actually, the `quoting`/`parskip` combo is a special case.

Comment: @lockstep ah, didn't know about that, thanks for the info.