# Eliminating extra vertical space around quotes in letters

Tags: spacing, letters, quoting

Eliminating vertical space around a quote, as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29642/9549), succeeds when the documentclass is `article`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{quoting}
\quotingsetup{vskip=0pt}

\begin{document}
\noindent We'd like to have 
\begin{quoting}
\emph{no vertical space}
\end{quoting}
around this quote.
\end{document}
```

[image: nospace]

but not when it is `letter`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{letter}
\usepackage{quoting}
\quotingsetup{vskip=0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Jack}
\noindent We'd like to have 
\begin{quoting}
\emph{no vertical space}
\end{quoting}
around this quote.
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image: space]

How to eliminate the vertical space surrounding quotes for documentclass `letter`?

Comment: Try `scrlettr2` class instead of `letter`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Replacing letter with scrlttr2 gives ! Undefined control sequence. \bbl@switch ...bel@beginsave }\languageshorthands{none}\ifcase \bbl@select@...

Comment: First, sorry about that typo, I meant `scrlttr2` of course. Please remove your `.aux` file before compiling with the other class. You have obviously

Comment: Do you include some other package not listed above?

Comment: That works. I was having trouble because scrlttr2 (Koma in general?) requires "\usepackage[english]{babel}".

Comment: KOMA `scrlttr2` is basically designed for usage with English and most European languages, such as French, Spanish, Italian, German, Croatian, Norwegian etc. Try `\usepackage[your_language]{babel}`. The style of letters is different in each country, the maintainers of KOMA cannot provide any specific letter style, that would mean to much effort.

Comment: too much effort, of course... sorry about that typo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `letter` class uses a non zero `\parskip`. So you get what you want by removing that added space:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{letter}
\usepackage{quoting}
\quotingsetup{vskip=-\parskip}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Jack}
\noindent We'd like to have
\begin{quoting}
\emph{no vertical space}
\end{quoting}
around this quote.
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]